# 3D Point Cloud Segmentation

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to develop a program to segment a 3D point cloud for my final year project.I'm new to this area.I hope to develop the program using kdtree & region growing.But I'm little bit confused about how am I going to develop it.If anyone have any idea or any sample projects relevant to this topic please help me.

THANK YOU.

Comment: Is there any new in this project? I'm going to start an similar project, maybe you have any new resources? For a first start I found this: http://www.ais.uni-bonn.de/papers/robocup2011_holz.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Your question is far too broad and you're not going to get answers. First investigate existing tools like the [Point Cloud Library](http://pointclouds.org/) and [lastools](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/) and see if you can identify something which they're lacking and implement that. I'm sure you have the academic background in this field and will know your question is a massive one.